# iOS: Getting the 3 letter language code from an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting current device language in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios)

I need the **3 letter language ISO** code as it's part of a call to another service. I can use NSLocale.CurrentLocale.Identifier to get the country code, but not language the device is set to.

Comment: You can get the two-letter country code and the two-letter language code from NSLocale but I don't know of any supplied API for getting the 3-letter version.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as "Exact Dupe"? None of the questions are asking about THREE character language codes?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is:

```
  [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Which as per Apple docs is:

> An ordered list of the user's preferred languages.
>
> Users choose a primary language when configuring a device, as described in Reviewing Language and Region Settings. They may also specify one or more secondary languages in order of preference for use when localization is unavailable in a higher priority language. Use this property to obtain the current user's ordered list of languages, presented as an array of locale identifier strings.

You can read more about that here: [IETF BCP 47](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag)

You can do the mapping yourself from what you get back to the equivalent ISO 3 letter code. There are only 47 entries in what comes back from the iOS call so not that big a deal.

Comment: This is incorrect. BCP 47 refers to a process, not the number of entries. There are around or more than some 300 entries. This answer has a better (but still out-of-date) list with code for a plist mapping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576947/ios-convert-iso-alpha-2-to-alpha-3-country-code. The full list that is more reasonably up to date is on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Comment: Not sure what your point is. The answer I wrote answers the question of how to get the users preferred language. That was and is the way to do it.